# Are memory mapped files faster than Named Pipes?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, named-pipes, communication-protocol

I was reading SQL Server Internals and Troubleshooting (Wrox) and it effectively says that `Shared Memory` is the default connection method, followed by TCP and then Named Pipes. What's curious though is that they say:

"Named Pipes was developed for local area networks (LANs) but it can be inefficient across slower networks such as wide area networks (WANs)"

I thought named pipes was strictly for IPC? And that in order to jump from IPC to network communication you had to use TCP/UDP. More interesting to me though is the mention of shared memory/memory mapped files - are they faster than NamedPipes/IPC?

Comment: IPC as a concept is not restricted to a single machine, so I'm not understanding "I thought named pipes was strictly for IPC"

Comment: That's a good point. I guess I mean I thought that Named-Pipes was strictly for communication across different processes / app domains on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, as usual, "It depends." If there is a lot of data involved, shared memory will cut out much of the overhead of copying it. But using a mapped file in this way still requires some adjunct form of IPC to coordinate access to the shared memory space.

Comment: Oh I see, so essentially you still need a pipe to coordinate how the memory mapped file is used, and in some cases it's just faster to use the pipe by itself? Interesting. I guess in my situation memory mapped files make sense then.

Comment: Just to confirm / deny my suspicions. Are pipes strictly for IPC on the same machine, or can they also be used over the network?

Comment: No, you don't need a pipe to coordinate. You can reserve an area of the MMF for flags and other control data. You have to be careful about synchronising of course. You can use a ManualResetEvent or other signalling event to synchronize too. (Pipes can be used over the network)

Comment: Yes, that's essentially correct; although there are other mechanisms than pipes that can potentially be used for coordination. For example, System V message queues, or Mach IPC ports.